# Cell Width in Tikzpicture creating error due to text width

Tags: tikz-pgf, landscape, tikz-calendar

I have the following code.

```
% DIN-A4 doublesided year calendar
% Author: Robert Krause
% License : Creative Commons attribution license
% Submitted to TeXample.net on 13 July 2012
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper, ngerman, 10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}           % Use the calendar.sty style

\usepackage{translator} % German Month and Day names
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % header and footer
\usepackage{fix-cm}     % Large year in header

\usepackage[landscape, headheight = 2cm, margin=.5cm,
  top = 3.2cm, nofoot]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>


\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% User defined
\def\year{2013}
% Names of Holidays are inserted by employing this macro
\def\termin#1#2{
  \node [anchor=north west, text width= 3.4cm] at
    ($(cal-#1.north west)+(3.0em, 0em)$) {\tiny{#2}};
}

%Header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{7ex}
\chead{
  \fontsize{35}{45}\selectfont\textbf{Kalendar \year Sachsen-Anhalt}\hfill
}
\rhead{
    \fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\textbf{Kalendar\textit{pedia\\}}
    \Large\textbf{Ferienkalender}
}
%Footer
\cfoot{\footnotesize\texttt{http://www.texample.net/}}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every day/.style={anchor = north}]
\calendar[
  dates=\year-01-01 to \year-12-31,
  name=cal,
  day yshift = 3.0em,
  day code=
  {
    % print days name
    \node[name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,every day,shape=rectangle,
    minimum width=1.8cm, minimum height= .53cm, text width = 2.4cm, draw = black]{\tikzdaytext};
    \draw (-1.8, -.1ex) node[anchor = west]{\footnotesize%
    \pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}};
  },
  execute before day scope=
  {
    \ifdate{day of month=1}
    {
      % Shift right
      \pgftransformxshift{2.4cm}
      % Print month name
      \draw (-1,0) node [shape=rectangle, minimum height= .53cm, minimum width= 1.8cm,
        text width = 2.4cm, fill = white, text= black, draw = black, text centered]
        {\textbf{\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}}};
    }{}
    \ifdate{workday}
    {
      % normal days are white
      \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=white}}
      % Vacation (Germany, Baden-Wuerrtemberg) gray background
      \ifdate{between=2012-12-24 and 2013-01-05}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-03-25 and 2013-04-05}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-05-21 and 2013-06-01}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-07-25 and 2013-09-07}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-10-28 and 2013-10-30}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-12-23 and 2014-01-04}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{ddd}
    }{}
    % Saturdays and half holidays (Christma's and New year's eve)
    \ifdate{Saturday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=yellow!10}}}{asd}
    \ifdate{equals=12-24}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!10}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=12-31}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!10}}}{}
    % Sundays and full holidays
    \ifdate{Sunday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=green!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=01-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=01-06}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=05-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=10-03}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=11-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=12-25}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=12-26}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    % Christian holidays
    \ifdate{equals=2013-03-29}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-04-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-05-09}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-05-20}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-05-30}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
  },
 execute at begin day scope=
  {
    % each day is shifted down according to the day of month
    \pgftransformyshift{-.53*\pgfcalendarcurrentday cm}
  }
];
% names of days....






% Print name of Holidays
\termin{\year-01-01}{Neujahr}
\termin{\year-01-06}{Heilige Drei KÃ¶nige}
\termin{2013-03-29}{Karfreitag}
\termin{2013-03-31}{Ostersonntag}
\termin{2013-04-01}{Ostermontag}
\termin{\year-05-01}{Tag der Arbeit}
\termin{2013-05-09}{Christi Himmelfahrt}
\termin{2013-05-19}{Pfingstsonntag}
\termin{2013-05-20}{Pfingstmontag}
\termin{2013-05-30}{Fronleichnam}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It gives me the following output. 
[image: Image with error]

But, I require the following output with adjust columns and text.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. I'm not sure I really understand what you're asking, but if you set `text width=4cm`, then the total width of the node will be 4cm + 2*the inner sep of the node. If you want the nodes to be narrower, you need to reduce the `text width`.

Comment: after reducing the text width, cell also reduced, but shifted to right and text goes out of the box.

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier for people to answer if you could turn your code into a minimal working example: basically a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, which contains everything needed to reproduce the problem, but *not more*. I might not be able to answer anyway, but I'm sure there are some who could. Perhaps some could answer without a complete example, but it makes it easier and more reliable if one can test the code you're actually using. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 for some discussion about making such MWEs, as they're called.

Comment: changed the question. Do you get some clue now?

Comment: Please help me. How can we add borders of caelnder with grey background, as shown in required outupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below seems to work.

[image]

I haven't looked at what the original code on Texample did, but some key points:

- Instead of using two different nodes for day number and day name, I put both in the same node, with the node text defined as

  ```
  \rlap{\tikzdaytext}\hspace{1em} {\footnotesize\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}}
  ```

  The `\rlap` means that `\tikzdaytext` is placed in a box with zero width, and the content of that box (`\tikzdaytext`) poking out of the box on the right side. By following that with 1em of horizontal space (`\hspace`), it wil make the day names aligned.
- For both month nodes and day nodes, use the same `text width`. The `minimum width` was irrelevant, so I removed it. Two things to note about node widths:

  - the total width of a node depends on the `inner sep` of the node, i.e. the distance from the node content to the border (default value of 0.333em), and the width of the content. With e.g. `text width=2cm` the content width is 2cm, so the total width is 2cm + 2*0.333em.
  - 12 months on an A4 page with a bit of space means that the nodes cannot be wider than about 2.2cm in total, so the `text width` has to be less than this.
- The code responsible for shifting each month to the right is the `\pgftransformxshift{<some length>}`. Following the discussion above, this has to be set to `\pgftransformxshift{<the value used for text width>+0.666em}`
- I modified the `\termin` macro. Instead of placing a node shifted some distance to the right of top left corner of the day node, with `anchor=north west`, I place the node at the top right corner with `anchor=north east`. I also reduced the `text width` to avoid overlapping.
- To make a gray box behind the calendar, you can for example add `\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds}` to the preamble, and add

  ```
  \scoped[on background layer]
    \node [draw, gray, fit=(current bounding box), inner sep=2pt] {};
  ```

  right before `\end{tikzpicture}` (i.e. after all the calendar stuff).

  The `inner sep` defines the space between the calendar and the edge of the box.

---

```
% DIN-A4 doublesided year calendar
% Author: Robert Krause
% License : Creative Commons attribution license
% Submitted to TeXample.net on 13 July 2012
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper, ngerman, 10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}           % Use the calendar.sty style

\usepackage{translator} % German Month and Day names
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % header and footer
\usepackage{fix-cm}     % Large year in header

\usepackage[landscape, headheight = 2cm, margin=.5cm,
  top = 3.2cm, nofoot]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>


\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% User defined
\def\year{2013}
% Names of Holidays are inserted by employing this macro
\def\termin#1#2{%
\node [anchor=north east, text width=1.5cm,font=\tiny,align=right] at (cal-#1.north east) {#2};
}

%Header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{7ex}
\chead{
  \fontsize{35}{45}\selectfont\textbf{Kalendar \year Sachsen-Anhalt}\hfill
}
\rhead{
    \fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\textbf{Kalendar\textit{pedia\\}}
    \Large\textbf{Ferienkalender}
}
%Footer
\cfoot{\footnotesize\texttt{http://www.texample.net/}}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every day/.style={anchor = north}]
\calendar[
  dates=\year-01-01 to \year-12-31,
  name=cal,
  day yshift = 3.0em,
  day code=
  {
    % print days name
    \node[
      name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,
      every day,
      minimum height=.53cm,
      text width = 2.1cm,
      draw = black,
      yshift=-1.5pt] 
       {\rlap{\tikzdaytext}\hspace{1em} {\footnotesize\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}}};
  },
  execute before day scope=
  {
    \ifdate{day of month=1}
    {
      % Shift right
      \pgftransformxshift{2.1cm+0.666em} % 0.666 = 2 * default inner sep of nodes
      % Print month name
      \node [
          minimum height=.53cm,
          text width = 2.1cm,
          fill = white,
          draw = black,
          text centered
        ]
        {\strut\textbf{\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}}};
    }{}
    \ifdate{workday}
    {
      % normal days are white
      \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=white}}
      % Vacation (Germany, Baden-Wuerrtemberg) gray background
      \ifdate{between=2012-12-24 and 2013-01-05}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-03-25 and 2013-04-05}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-05-21 and 2013-06-01}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-07-25 and 2013-09-07}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-10-28 and 2013-10-30}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
      \ifdate{between=2013-12-23 and 2014-01-04}{%
        \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{ddd}
    }{}
    % Saturdays and half holidays (Christma's and New year's eve)
    \ifdate{Saturday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=yellow!10}}}{asd}
    \ifdate{equals=12-24}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!10}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=12-31}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!10}}}{}
    % Sundays and full holidays
    \ifdate{Sunday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=green!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=01-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=01-06}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=05-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=10-03}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=11-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=12-25}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=12-26}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    % Christian holidays
    \ifdate{equals=2013-03-29}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-04-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-05-09}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-05-20}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2013-05-30}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
  },
 execute at begin day scope=
  {
    % each day is shifted down according to the day of month
    \pgftransformyshift{-.53*\pgfcalendarcurrentday cm}
  }
];
% names of days....


% Print name of Holidays
\termin{\year-01-01}{Neujahr}
\termin{\year-01-06}{Heilige Drei KÃ¶nige}
\termin{2013-03-29}{Karfreitag}
\termin{2013-03-31}{Ostersonntag}
\termin{2013-04-01}{Ostermontag}
\termin{\year-05-01}{Tag der Arbeit}
\termin{2013-05-09}{Christi Himmelfahrt}
\termin{2013-05-19}{Pfingstsonntag}
\termin{2013-05-20}{Pfingstmontag}
\termin{2013-05-30}{Fronleichnam}


\scoped[on background layer]
\node [fit=(current bounding box), % means the node just fits around everything in the tikzpicture
       draw, % draw outline
       fill, % and fill
       gray, % with this colour
%       inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth % and with this amount of space between frame and content
       % with -0.5\pgflinewidth the framn will overlap with the edges of the vells
       % if you want a gap, use some positive value, e.g.
       inner sep=2pt
] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats Great ! I have a minor issue. How we can add rectangle around calendar with grey color.

Comment: Please tell me that, how we can show week number on every Monday? Thanku

Comment: @Alvi I can fix the frame later, but I don't know how to do the week number (at least not without some digging), so I suggest you ask a new question about that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Waiting for you to fix the frame.

Comment: @Alvi See updated answer.

Comment: how we can add grey color in the background of frame?

Comment: @Alvi See updated answer (didn't update the screenshot).

Comment: I have edit it. But, background color is showing at the front of calendar. Where should I do to change position backward.

Comment: @Alvi Did you add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` to the preamble and `\scoped[on background layer]` immediately before the final `\node`, as in my answer?

Comment: Thanks ! its working